# How to rotate an object in SceneKit editor with Xcode 10

Tags: ios, xcode, rotation, editor, scenekit

I'm following a tutorial where you can see the Earth rotating. All seems really easy: you put a sphere object with SceneKit Editor and then you add a rotation action.[image]

This is the action I'm adding:

[image]

The thing is that in the project I download from the internet all is working perfect but when I do this in a new project my Earth doesn't rotate one single pixel! All the attributes I can see in the inspector seems to be exactly the same.

Probably there is some silly thing I am not considering...

Answer (score 0):

I wasn't able to find `RotateByAxisAngle` in the Apple developer documentation on SceneKit animation. Is it possible the tutorial is slightly out of date? You might want to try one of the other functions listed in the [Apple documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/scenekit/scnaction/1523805-rotate). Otherwise I'd try setting one of your rotation values from `0.00` to `6.28319` or 360 degrees in radians.

Comment: I just added the action I'm using. I'm not using any code here, just SceneKit editor. I'm working with Xcode 10 and the tutorial is for the same versión. I think I am missing something... :)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, the rotation wasn't working after adding a **RotateBy Axis Angle Action**, but after I updated the **Angle** value, it started rotating.

To change the Angle value, just select your Action from the Actions bar and then from **Attributes Inspector** menu, change the **Angle**.

The default Angle value is set to `0`, just change it to `1` and notice you should also set Axis values and they shouldn't be all zero, like below:

[image]

Now the rotation should work all well.